# Xamarin Forms, which project to place file access code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm fairly new to Xamarin Forms and I have a project that for the moment just targets Android.  I'm trying to understand the correct place to put logic for uploading images from the mobile device to either Azure blob storage or FTP them to a server.  The logic to upload to Azure or FTP I already have working, I'm just trying to understand if that belongs in the PCL/Forms project, or should it go in the Android project?  Are there pro's/con's to place it in either project?

Comment: It depends upon if you need access to files "outside" of your app's sandbox, what type of "file access" are you trying to perform?

Comment: I'm mainly uploading images from the local camera folder and then removing them once uploaded

Comment: You can add the selection login in the platform specific projects and then the upload logic in your PCL project as a shared logic,